# DataGrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в WPF DataGrid добавлять динамически строки и колонки. Затем вручную вводить данные на форме, считывать их и выводить в другой DataGrid??

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int M { get; private set; }
    public int N { get; private set; }

    public DataTable dt;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MatrixSize_1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
        this.MatrixSize_2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    public IList MatrixSize_1 { get; private set; }
    public IList MatrixSize_2 { get; private set; }
    public object Matrix { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        M= (int)e.AddedItems[0];
    }
    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        N = (int)e.AddedItems[0];
        this.UpdateMatrix(M,N);
        this.Matric.Width = M * 23.1;
    }
    void UpdateMatrix(int M,int N)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        for (var i = 0; i < M; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("c" + i, typeof(double)));
        for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            var r = dt.NewRow();
            for (int c = 0; c < M; c++)
                r[c] = c;
            dt.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        this.Matrix = dt.DefaultView;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Matrix"));
    }
```

У меня скомпилилось нужное количество столбцов и строк. Теперь Я на форме ввел значения в ячейки и как эти значения достать из DataGrid??

Answer (score 0):

Давайте по-порядку:

### Динамическое добавление строк и колонок

Похожий вопрос задавался в англо-язычной версии и, если нет проблем с переводом, то вот [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452134/filling-a-datagrid-with-dynamic-columns).

### Перенос данных из одного DataGrid в другой

Если не ошибаюсь, чтобы назначить данные из одного DataGrid другому, достаточно указать тот же самый источник DataSource другому DataGrid. Опять же, есть ответ на английской версии, [попробуйте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398441/how-to-set-the-datasource-of-a-datagrid-in-wpf).

### Рекомендация по считыванию размеров матрицы

Вместо TextBox лучше воспользоваться [NumericUpDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-4.8), он изначально работает только с целыми значениями и Вы можете установить диапазон значений для размеров матрицы.

Comment: Чёт всё же не выходит, считывать данные которые ввел пользователь на форме..
Точнее я не нашёл ответа в данных ссылках.

Comment: Разбейте задачу на более мелкие шаги, например, просто создать 2 DataGrid, добавить в первый что-то, потом попытаться перенести данные во-второй. Возможно вы пытаетесь сделать всё и сразу. :)

Comment: да, так и сделал, всё получилось по божески)